# Multiple Search Criteria (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, search

So my problem is:
I have a List of a custom Type {Id as Integer, Tag() as String},
and i want to perform a multiple-criteria search on it; eg:
SearchTags={"Document","HelloWorld"}
Results of the Search will be placed a ListBox (ListBox1) in this format:
resultItem.id & " - " & resultItem.tags

I already tried everything i could find on forums, but it didn't work for me (It was for db's or for string datatypes)

Now, i really need your help. Thanks in advance.

```
    For Each MEntry As EntryType In MainList
        For Each Entry In MEntry.getTags
            For Each item As String In Split(TextBox1.Text, " ")
                If Entry.Contains(item) Then
                    If TestIfItemExistsInListBox2(item) = False Then
                        ListBox1.Items.Add(item & " - " & Entry.getId)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
```

Example Custom Array:

```
(24,{"snippet","vb"})
(32,{"console","cpp","helloworld"})
and so on...
```

I searched for ("Snippet vb test"):

```
snippet vb helloWorld - 2
snippet vb tcpchatEx - 16
cs something
test
```

So, i'll get everything that contains one of my search phrases.

I expected following:

```
snippet vb tcp test
snippet vb dll test
snippet vb test metroui
```

So, i want to get everything that contains all my search phrases.

---

My entire, code-likely class

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub
    Dim MainList As New List(Of EntryType)
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MainList.Clear()
        Dim thr As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf thr1)
        thr.SetApartmentState(Threading.ApartmentState.MTA)
        thr.Start()
    End Sub
    Delegate Sub SetTextCallback([text] As String)
    Private Sub SetTitle(ByVal [text] As String) ' source <> mine
        If Me.TextBox1.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetTitle)
            Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {[text]})
        Else
            Me.Text = [text]
        End If
    End Sub
    Sub thr1()
        Dim linez As Integer = 1
        Dim linex As Integer = 1
        For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("index.db")
            linez += 1
        Next

        For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("index.db")
            Try
                Application.DoEvents()
                Dim a As saLoginResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of saLoginResponse)(line) ' source <> mine
                Application.DoEvents()
                MainList.Add(New EntryType(a.id, Split(a.tags, " ")))
                linex += 1
                SetTitle("Search (loading, " & linex & " of " & linez & ")")
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        Next
        SetTitle("Search")
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim searchTags() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(" ")
        Dim query = MainList.Where(Function(et) et.Tags.Any(Function(tag) searchTags.Contains(tag))).ToList
        For Each et In query
            ListBox1.Items.Add(et.Id)
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) ' test
        MsgBox(Mid(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString, 1, 6)) ' test
    End Sub 'test, removeonrelease
End Class
Public Class EntryType
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Tags() As String
    Public Sub New(ByVal _id As Integer, ByVal _tags() As String)
        Me.Id = Id
        Me.Tags = Tags
    End Sub
    Public Function GetTags() As String
        'to tell the Listbox what to display
        Return Tags
    End Function
    Public Function GetId() As Integer
        'to tell the Listbox what to display
        Return Id
    End Function
End Class
```

I also edited your EntryType class; I added a constructor, removed toString and added GetTags and GetID.

---

Example "DB" im working with ("db" as "index.db" in exec dir):

```
{"tags":"vb.net lol test qwikscopeZ","id":123456}
{"tags":"vb.net lol test","id":12345}
{"tags":"vb.net lol","id":1234}
{"tags":"vb.net","id":123}
{"tags":"cpp","id":1}
{"tags":"cpp graphical","id":2}
{"tags":"cpp graphical fractals","id":3}
{"tags":"cpp graphical fractals m4th","id":500123}
```

---

Error:

```
Debugger:Exception Intercepted: _Lambda$__1, Form2.vb line 44
An exception was intercepted and the call stack unwound to the point before the call from user code where the exception occurred.  "Unwind the call stack on unhandled exceptions" is selected in the debugger options.
Time: 13.11.2014 03:46:10
Thread:<No Name>[5856]
```

Comment: can you give some db sample data

Comment: It's not a db, its a array of a custom type (id as integer,tag() as string)

Comment: The `GetId` and `GetTags` functions are redundant since you can just call the properties directly - FYI

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `Lambda` query. The `Where` filters on a predicate, since `Tags` is an `Array` you can use the `Any` function to perform a search based on another `Array`-`SearchTags`. You can store each class object in the Listbox since it stores Objects, you just need to tell it what to display(see below).

```
Public Class EntryType
  Public Property Id As Integer
  Public Property Tags() As As String
  Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    'to tell the Listbox what to display
    Return String.Format("{0} - {1}", Me.Id, String.Join(Me.Tags, " "))
  End Function
End Class

Dim searchTags = textbox1.Text.Split(" "c)
Dim query = mainlist.Where(Function(et) et.Tags.Any(Function(tag) searchTags.Contains(tag))).ToList
For Each et In query
   Listbox1.Items.Add(et)
Next
```

Comment: There are a couple of questions in that last comment, can you answer them?

Comment: My application crashed in the Line where query is created; Value cant be NULL; (see op); I need to get all results which match all my search queries, not just one/+ of them.

Comment: I see a place where you Clear the MainList - the query cannot run if it is empty.

Comment: I wait until the query is populated

Comment: Did you debug and check the mainList variable before it ran?

Comment: Yes, i used a msgBox to display the tags and it's populated.

Comment: I am not sure how else to help you. I know my query works. Something is amiss in your code. I hope you can find it.

Comment: Simple - I want to search like in the Windows Explorer (except * and that stuff). I really dont know whats wrong in my code...

Comment: Debug it, don't just place `MsgBox`s. Follow your code, checking variables and there values. If you use a `Try/Catch` report the error somewhere - like `Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString)`

Comment: It simply wont work for me. Using VS2013 Ultimate, please test my code. It loads correctly, but i'll get a null exception when trying to search.

Comment: No way I could, i don't know what type of object `saLoginResponse` is

Comment: Its from a JSON Example, it contains (Tags as string, id as int)

Comment: When you debug, how many `EntryType`s are in `MainList` right before the query? Are there any searchTags in the array? Do you know how to debug?

Comment: When i search, there's 1 search tag (i also tried w/ 2) ("cpp") in the SearchList array. EntryTypes are getting assigned after loading the json file, but then their ID-Value is 0, and the tag() array includes the id... i dont know whats the problem. - nvm, im away for 10 hrs.

Comment: This is why I keep saying DEBUG, DEBUG, DEBUG, set a breakpoint at the start of the looping from the reading of the file, see what is being set in the `a As saLoginResponse` variable. I bet it is not doing what you think it is. Adjust the parsing or ask another question for that - fix it and then my part will work.

Comment: Okay, i made it work again... But now, if i use your query, it makes the same thing again: It lists everything that matches one of the searchtags, but i want, that only results will be listed, which match all my searchtags.